# Is there a CMS that runs on Google App Engine that is comparable to Plone (in certain respects)?

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine, content-management-system

I spent a while writing apps for Plone and feel that Plone "does content management right" compared to many other CMS offerings.  I'm wondering if there's a comparable CMS that runs on Google App Engine.  The big pluses that I'm looking for are:

1. WSIWYG Content Management - I like how Plone's content management features don't require logging into a hidden management UI.  It made my life easier training my users because I didn't have to teach them two different UIs - the content management features are integrated into the site's UI.
2. Everything is a "content" object - Plone treats most anything that users create as a content object: images, articles, events, even users (if you want), meaning Plone's content management features can be applied to all of these things: access control, workflow, etc.
3. Workflow - absolutely essential for modeling user tasks in the software.  States & transitions.  Scripts that run on state transitions.
4. Content objects having "strong-typing" - Plone allows you to create (in software parlance) content "classes" whose relationships with other instances of content types are restricted by type.  So for instance, I can create an `article` type that has a reference to an `event`, and the UI makes sure I can create `article`s and reference only `event` objects for the `event` field of my `article` objects.  (The creation of these "classes" can be a developer task or be hidden behind an admin UI)

Does a CMS for Google App Engine exist that has these features?  Either Python or Java is acceptable for me.

Answer (score 0):

Vosao CMS works with google app-engine. I have not tried Plone CMS. But Vosao CMS has all the features you are looking for.

it has  versioning, workflow, WYSIWYG editing, design templates. Not sure about your 4th point. Im not sure what you mean by saying:

> Content objects having "strong-typing" - Plone allows you to create
>   (in software parlance) content "classes" whose relationships with
>   other instances of content types are restricted by type. So for
>   instance, I can create an article type that has a reference to an
>   event, and the UI makes sure I can create articles and reference only
>   event objects for the event field of my article objects. (The creation
>   of these "classes" can be a developer task or be hidden behind an
>   admin UI)

check this google code page for [vasao CMS](http://code.google.com/p/vosao/)

Also see this [FAQ page about vasao CMS](http://help.bruneimedical.com/faq)

For further reference check the [website of vasao cms](http://www.vosao.org/)

Comment: From what I'm seeing, you log into a separate "management" UI for Vosao to create or modify content.  This is one thing I'm trying to avoid.  My users are content-creators as well as content-consumers.

Comment: @FMM you can configure this in vasao CMS to allow your users by granting them privileges to edit/modify the content. if that user has privileges to edit/modify privileges to your content-consumers then they can add/edit/delete the content too..

Comment: You're missing what I'm saying.  I don't want add/edit/delete to occur in a different UI than the view UI.  I want the users' logged-in state, and the role- and/or group-based permissions assigned to that user dictates whether they can create/edit/delete content as visible by widgets present or absent in the UI.